# How to add an addon manually to firefox

Tags: software-installation, firefox, add-on

I am completely new to Ubuntu and i have been trying to install a addon to Firefox.

Name of addon: `bytubeD` (commonly known as "bulk youtube downloader")
Developers site: http://msram.github.io/bytubed/

I could not add directly to Firefox because it is discontinued and wont show up in Firefox addons. If you go to the developers page you can see there is two download for Windows and Linux. I downloaded it but how do i install it?

Comment: http://msram.github.io/bytubed/2013/09/27/disabling-bytubed.html read isn't hard, luck.

Comment: try the avinash's answer, its working..

Answer (score 1):

click [here](http://msram.github.io/bytubed/dev-versions/1.1.2a2.xpi) to install bytubed addon on firefox only if you trust the author.

[image]

Comment: Would it be too much harm add a bit more of information? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the add-on (.xpi file).
2. Open Firefox, go to Tools → addons → extensions.
3. Drag & drop your .xpi file onto the Firefox window.
4. Then follow the instructions.